# How can I communicate between Pipe and Component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let logDetails of logDetails | search : term" >
```

I have a Pipe in which I want to use a variable. Same variable has been defined in my Component. How can I pass this value from Component to Pipe?

```ts
//Pipe Structure

transform(value, [term], newVal) {
  if (value == undefined && newVal == undefined) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return value.filter((item) => item.LogString.startsWith(term));
  }
}

//Component Structure

newVal(a) {
  this.newChildData = a;
  console.log(this.newChildData);
}
```

I want to pass `newChildData` of Component into `newVal` of Pipe.

// HTML Template

Comment: You pass it in via the template when you invoke the pipe. Parameters are covered in the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. But I am not sending newVal through template.There is some "term" Field which I am taking from Text Box and sending.

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying you need to send the other parameters it needs with it! RTFM.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe.It  worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's either you use the pipe in the template and pass new value into it.

```
<div>{{ yourValue | yourPipe: newChildData }}<div>
```

Or, since Pipe is just a Javascript class, you can import it in your component and use it.

```
const pipe = new youPipe();
const result = pipe.transform(yourValue, newChildData);
```

But I won't suggest the later.

If you want to use the pipe programmatically, consider splitting the transform logic to service, then import and use that service in both `pipe` and `component`.